# Can one remap kernel virtual address for use by kernel code

Tags: linux-kernel

I am porting a large application to ARM32 Linux and splitting off the hardware stuff into a device driver. Nearly all of the extensive driver code uses absolute addresses to access buffers and I/O related variables and registers. I'd have to have to change all that to pointer relative addresses - a lot of code is in assembler as well.

From user space it is simple to use mmap to ask for a target virtual address for physical memory (via /dev/mem) so that side poses no issue.

But how can I do similar in kernel code ? IOremap and Memremap give you a random kernel virtual address, worse, loading a driver using INSMOD places both code and data (.bbs) in vmalloc memory.
remap_PFN_range can be used to map kernel memory to user space via mmap call (and with that ask for a given virtual address range) - but how can that be used from the kernel itself if at all ?

So for example, say I have a buffer at physical address 0x60000000 - how can I tell the Kernel to map that to a given kernel accessible virtual address (perhaps also 0x60000000 but could be anything as long as its known at compile time) ?

So far I have spent days surfing anything that mentions remapping but am not finding the "golden" answer. Anybody know if one exists ?

Comment: Bear in mind that the overall virtual address space has a split between user space and kernel space. Virtual address 0x60000000 will lie in user space.

Comment: Yes correct - in my case I have a 3/1 split so everything above 0xC0000000 is fair game. Getting to grips with Linux's page table management - should be able to achieve my goal borrowing some RAM from CMA. Specifying desired virtual address is not available in Linux ARM but in some other architectures it is (Macro mk_pte_phys). Should be able to use it in ARM - seems very straight forward at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no "easy" way to do that.

[This](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/x86_64/mm.txt) document explains the memory layout of the Linux kernel memory, and as you see, modules has a specific mapping space which can't be changed as long as you load your code with [init_module](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/init_module.2.html) syscall, and dynamic memory that's allocated using stuff like `kmalloc` also has a specific range.

Maybe you'll be able to hack something together to create a buffer at a known address, but if my memory doesn't fool me, Linux kind of depends on the layout I mentioned above for some fundamental stuff (page faults etc...).

Comment: Well, if it would be easy - I'm sure I'd have an answer :-) Well, nothing really stops me from accessing the first level kernel page table (1Mb splits) and taking over a couple of unused entries in whatever virtual space I desire and point them to any physical memory I can use (such as a reserved section that Linux will not touch).

Comment: There are some open source tools that can turn a compiled binary to PIC. Of course couldn't find something that does this specifically for LKMs as they are PIC already lol

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have the answer and it's embarrassingly simple.
In my case I am running a STM32MP157 chip under buildroot. It so happens 512MBytes of DRAM is placed at 0xC0000000 physical. This means kernel space virtual address = physical address. PAGE_OFFSET and PHYS_OFFSET are 0xC0000000 so they simply cancel out.
Right, to display a nice logo on startup a 3MByte framebuffer is allocated in CMA memory which starts at 0xD8000000. This is done in early kernel init and is the first thing in CMA. Later on I allocate more framebuffers via DRM but the first one stays.

It's unused after kernel boot - except it now isn't. It's my perfect solution - just read and write directly into 0xD8000000 to 0xD83FFFFF (physical location and size of that framebuffer). All the variables I need to have at locations known at compile time are located into that space. Directly accessible, no pointers needed. No need to modify my existing code other than tell the linker to place the variables at 0xD8000000.